# Setup Multi-Region Install by Store or Website

Tags: multistore, currency, installation, multicurrency

We are building a Magento CE  website with UK, EU and US regions for a single brand and less than 1000 products that may be available in some or all of the regions.

We want to avoid currency fluctuations so we will have separate EURO, GBP and DOLLAR bank accounts per region rather than converting from base currency at cart to region currency.

Is it best to setup our install with 3 separate "websites" under 1 magento installation? Each website to have a separate base currency and each using separate merchant ID so that there is no currency conversion needed per region from viewing/selecting/adding product to cart up to payment and forwarding of funds to relevant currency bank account.

Or is it an option to do this with 3 "Stores" under 1 "Website" under 1 magento installation using solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568629/magento-store-views-and-multiple-currencies-checkout-using-base-currency-alw)?

This is more applicable to the Sagepay payment method we intend to use but we will also use paypal or stripe for payment.

Comment: Do you plan on manually setting the price for all 3 websites?

Comment: @Cags Yes, I will probably have to manually set the price for the 3 websites unless there is a better way.

Comment: from memory, if you wish to manually control the prices on the three 'sites' you will have to use website not store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From @Cags comments a formulated answer**

If you want to manage prices without currency calculation go with separate websites, you can set the prices for each product/website.

The other choice is to go with global prices and let currency calculation do the magic.

So 3 websites and price per website setting. `System / Configuration / Catalog / Price` -> `Catalog Price Scope` => `Website`

Answer (score 0):

Correct, three separate websites, except Global currency prices are display currency only, checkout is always in the base currency hence why you need the three websites. You do however need to maintain all the product prices individually per currency/website or have scripts that perform the updates for you.